# pyPEG2 parsing of newlines

Tags: python, newline, pypeg

I'm trying to use [pyPEG2](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/) to translate MoinMoin markup to Markdown, and I need to pay attention to newlines in certain cases. However, I can't even get my newline parsing tests to work.  I'm new to pyPEG and my Python is rusty.  Please bear with me.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from pypeg2 import *
import re

class Newline(List):
    grammar = re.compile(r'\n')

parse("\n", Newline)
parse("""
""", Newline)
```

This results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pyPegNewlineTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    parse("\n", Newline)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pypeg2/__init__.py", line 667, in parse
    t, r = parser.parse(text, thing)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pypeg2/__init__.py", line 794, in parse
    raise r
  File "<string>", line 2

    ^
SyntaxError: expecting match on \n
```

It's as if pypeg is inserting an empty line after the \n.

Trying other options such as

```
    grammar = re.compile(r'\n', re.MULTILINE)
    grammar = re.compile(r'\r\n|\r|\n', re.MULTILINE)
    grammar = contiguous(re.compile(r'\r\n|\r|\n', re.MULTILINE))
```

and various combinations of those don't change the error message (although I don't think I tried all combinations). Changing `Newline` to subclass `str` instead of `List` doesn't change the error either.

**Update**

I have figured out that pypeg is stripping the newline before parsing it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from pypeg2 import *                 
import re
class Newline(str):
    grammar = contiguous(re.compile(r'a'))

parse("\na", Newline)
parse("""
a""", Newline)

print("Success, of a sort.")
```

Running this results in:

```
Success, of a sort.
```

If I override the `Newline`'s `parse` method I don't even see the newline.  The first thing it gets is the "a".  This is consistent with what I'm seeing elsewhere.  pypeg strips all leading whitespace, even when you specify `contiguous`.

So, that's what's happening.  Not sure what to do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes by default pypeg remove the whitespaces including the newlines.
This is easly configurable by setting the optional `whitespace` argument in the `parse()` function, e.g. in:

```
parse("\na", Newline, whitespace=re.compile(r"[ \t\r]"))
```

Doing so spaces and tabs will still be skipped, but not newlines `\n`.
With this example the parser now correctly find the syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: expecting match on a
```